# Kafka in Docker not working

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-python

I am trying to use `wurstmeister\kafka-docker` image with  `docker-compose`, but I am having real problems with connecting everything.

All the posts or questions that I check, seems not to have any problems, but I am frankly lost. (And there are at least two questions in SO that try to address the problem)

I believe that the problem is my poor understanding of the networking of `docker`. So the problem:

I can consume and produce from the same container of kafka, but, when I try to create another container (or use my laptop with a python client) I got several errors related to the `advertised.host.name` parameter (in the image this parameter is `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME`)

I already try setting this variable in lot of ways, but it simply don't work.

So I am looking for a authorative answer (i.e. how to set automatically those parameters and what is it meaning)  how to set the `docker-compose.yml`

This is mine:

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"

kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
 # hostname: kafka
  ports:
    - "9092"
  links:
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zk:2181"
```

**UPDATE**

Following the advise of @dnephin, I modified the `start-kafka.sh` in the following lines:

```
...
if [[ -z "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT" ]]; then
    export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=$(hostname -i)
fi
...
```

and  remove `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka"` from the `docker-compose.yml`

I started the containers in the canonical way:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Both of the containers are running:

```
$ docker-compose ps
           Name                          Command               State                     Ports                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
infraestructura_kafka_1       start-kafka.sh                   Up      0.0.0.0:32768->9092/tcp                    
infraestructura_zookeeper_1   /opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServe ...   Up      0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Afterwards I did:

```
docker-compose logs
```

And everything run smoothly.

For checking the ip addresses:

```
$ KAFKA_IP=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' infraestructura_kafka_1)                                                                                                            
$ echo $KAFKA_IP
172.17.0.4

and

$ ZK_IP=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' infraestructura_zookeeper_1)                                                                                                           
$ echo $ZK_IP 
172.17.0.3
```

Then I execute in two differents consoles:

A producer:

```
$ docker run --rm --interactive wurstmeister/kafka /opt/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic grillo --broker-list 171.17.0.4:9092
```

A consumer:

```
$ docker run --rm --interactive  wurstmeister/kafka /opt/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic grillo --from-beginning --zookeeper 172.17.0.3:2181
```

Almost immediately, warnings start flying all over the screen:

```
[2016-03-11 00:39:17,010] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(grillo)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(1001,ba53d4fd7595,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:75)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:74)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:119)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
[2016-03-11 00:39:17,013] WARN [console-consumer-79688_9dd5f575d557-1457656747003-f1ed369d-leader-finder-thread], Failed to find leader for Set([grillo,0]) (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFin
derThread)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(grillo)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(1001,ba53d4fd7595,9092))] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:73)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:75)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:74)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:119)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
        ... 3 more
```

and so on

In the console of the producer, I wrote some sentences:

```
$ docker run --rm --interactive klustera/kafka /opt/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic grillo --broker-list 171.17.0.4:9092                                                           
Hola
¿Cómo estáń?
¿Todo bien?
```

And a few moments later, I got this response:

```
[2016-03-11 00:39:28,955] ERROR Error when sending message to topic grillo with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
[2016-03-11 00:40:28,956] ERROR Error when sending message to topic grillo with key: null, value: 16 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
[2016-03-11 00:41:28,956] ERROR Error when sending message to topic grillo with key: null, value: 12 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

And in the `docker-compose logs`

```
...
zookeeper_1 | 2016-03-11 00:39:07,072 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@651] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x153631368b1000b type:create c
xid:0x2 zxid:0x47 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers
zookeeper_1 | 2016-03-11 00:39:07,243 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@651] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x153631368b1000b type:create c
xid:0x19 zxid:0x4b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/console-consumer-79688/owners/grillo Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/console-consumer-79688/owners/grillo
zookeeper_1 | 2016-03-11 00:39:07,247 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@651] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x153631368b1000b type:create $xid:0x1a zxid:0x4c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/console-consumer-79688/owners Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/console-consumer-79688/owners
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

I made it work, at least, in `docker-machine`:

First, I defined a variable with the name of the `docker-machine`:

```
DOCKER_VM=kafka_test
```

Then, I modify the `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "${DOCKER_MACHINE_IP}"
```

Lastly, in the environment of the `docker-machine`, I execute:

```
DOCKER_MACHINE_IP=$(docker-machine ip $DOCKER_VM) docker-compose up -d
```

But in the laptop (I mean, without using a virtual machine, it doesn't work)

Comment: Just checking if I got it ok: it works when you run one container but when you create another one (when the first is running) it fails? Or the problem is that you cannot connect to the kafka container?

Comment: When I try to connect using the consumer or the producer fails... thanks for the question

Comment: I suppose you really wanted to set it to KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST instead. this line will assign IP address to variable which supposed to have port number : 'export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=$(hostname -i)'

Answer (score 41):

My solution to this issue is slightly different. I configure Kafka to advertise on `kafka` host and, because it's exposed on the host machine on `localhost:9092`, I add an entry in `/etc/hosts` for `kafka` to resolve to `localhost`. By doing this Kafka can be accessed from both other Docker containers and from localhost.

docker-compose.yml:

```
  my-web-service:
    build: ./my-web-service
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    links:
     - kafka
  kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka:0.10.2.0"
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    links: 
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```

Updated hosts file:

```
more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost kafka
```

Comment: Thanks, for me `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka` was the key.  Didn't need updated host file or links for another compose service in same network to connect to kafka using `kafa:9092` as broker

Comment: Using the hosts file is not the correct solution... https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: How do you deal with multiple clusters? They will have to use different ports to be accessible from the host machine.

Answer (score 9):

For developing app in localhost, there is a solution in the [documentation](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker#advertised-hostname): "HOSTNAME_COMMAND"

```
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  ports:
    - 9092:9092
environment:
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}'"
```

Hope this help others...

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the most portable way.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the value you use for `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` will change depending on how the container can be reached.

If you're trying to connect from another container, using `kafka` should be correct (as long as you use set that name as the link alias).

If you're trying to connect from the host, that name isn't going to work. You'd need to use the container IP address, which you can get using `docker inspect`.  However the container IP address will change, so it might be better to set this from inside the container using `$(hostname -i)` to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Where do I have to put `$(hostname -i)`?  In the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: In the entrypoint script , or some script that runs in the container.

Answer (score 4):

here's an improved version of @radek1st answer.

`links` is the old docker way, `networks` is the current method.

imo, making any sort of system change isn't good and should never be needed. it also kind of defeats the purpose of using Docker.

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  sb:
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    networks:
     - sb
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: ${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
     - sb
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Then I use the follow bash script to start things. This allows me to override the Kafka hostname for local development.  `./startup.sh localhost`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo KAFKA_HOSTNAME=${1:-kafka} > .env
docker-compose up -d
```

Read more -

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Comment: Note: this setup only allows other containers in the network to reach Kafka, not the host as well. See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 3):

Just try the following & use service discovery for example [this one](https://www.consul.io/).

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
kafka:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  links:
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Or you use this one:

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports: 
    - "2181"
kafka:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "9092"
  links: 
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
    DOCKER_HOST: 192.168.59.103:2375
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Thanks, `consul.io` seems very cool!, but, Could you be more specific, I mean,  Where do you get the `192.168.59.103`? Could you point to a tutorial setting consul in this scenario?

Comment: Have you read the doc (https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker)?


Modify the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in docker-compose.yml to match your docker host IP (Note: Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the host ip if you want to run multiple brokers.)

Comment: As I said in the question it works if I am using `docker-machine` but no if I am using my laptop as the docker host ( I am in GNU /Linux)

Comment: Thanks @user2550587 Which are the differences between the first one and the second one? (I am using `consul` now)

Comment: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103

Comment: Could you be please more specific in how to assign the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME`?

Answer (score 1):

Not direct answer, but if anyone is trying to understand the kafka docker networking `wurstmeister\kafka-docker` author has written an amazing wiki write up on [network connectivity](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity).

It explains the three main requirements for configuring Kafka networking through docker-compose.

1. Each Broker must be able to talk to Zookeeper - for leader election
   etc.
2. Each Broker must be able to talk to every other Broker - for
   replication etc.
3. Each Consumer/Producer must be able to talk to
   every Broker - for reading/writing data etc.

[image: Kafka Network]

Few Gotcha's:

> Because it is only possible to bind to each unique port once on a
> single interface, we can no longer publish the Broker port (9092).
> Instead, we simply expose the port.
>
> ports:
>
> - "9092"

> Since Kafka 0.9.0 - it has been possible to specify multiple ports for
> listening on. This is to facilitate support for multiple protocols
> (i.e. PLAINTEXT,SASL,SSL etc) and separate internal and external
> traffic. With this change, host.name and port have been deprecated in
> favour of listeners. advertised.host.name and advertised.port have
> been deprecated in favour of advertised.listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue use below code：

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper
  environment:
    HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk '{ print $$2}' | awk -F: '{print $$2}''"
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had the issue because the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"` was missing in the kafka environment.

```
 kafka:
    image : wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper
```

Comment: This won't work when youre using Kafka clients in other docker containers or multiple Kafka containers

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to update the docker-compose.yml `environment` configuration for `kafka`

Previous has `localhost`

```
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
```

Updated replaces `localhost` with `kafka`:

```
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9092
```

full:

```
networks:
  kafka-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  kafka:
  zookeeper_data:
  zookeeper_txns:


services:
  kafka:
    image: "bitnami/kafka:2.7.0"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
      - KAFKA_CFG_NUM_PARTITIONS=10
      - KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      #       10MB max message size (vs 1MB default)
      - KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=10485760
      - KAFKA_CFG_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=10485760
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  zookeeper:
    image: "bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.2"
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in regards to kafka bailing on the following error type:

> [2022-05-27 15:53:41,940] ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/1, node already exists and owner '72062330391560192' does not match current session '72058027900010496' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)

```
[2022-05-27 15:53:41,944] ERROR [KafkaServer id=1] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:126)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.getAfterNodeExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1904)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1842)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1809)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:324)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

This is what worked for me:

## identify which volumes to remove

```
docker volume ls
```

## remove them

```
docker volume rm beepboop_zookeeper_data
docker volume rm beepboop_zookeeper_txns
```

## restart kafka

```
docker-compose restart kafka
```

Answer (score -3):

I just update my host file and add:

`127.0.0.1 localhost kafkaserver`

It works fine for me. I used the same docker image on windows 10.

Comment: This explains how to do it correctly https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/